# SQL Plus trim trailing spaces when no need

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have my pl/sql code written in a file:

```
create or replace proc p1 as
begin
  null; <here i have lots of trailing spaces>
end;
/
```

When I execute the script in sqlplus the procedure p1 doesn't include the spaces in line #4.

How can I reserve these spaces?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't this way -- why would you want to? What are you trying to do here? Perhaps knowing that someone can point you in the right direction.

Comment: The reason is that when I later compare the source code, I have differences in the code because of the missing white spaces at the end of the line.

Comment: Why do you need the spaces in the original source?

Comment: I don't. But I cannot control the original source

Comment: It's your source code comparison tool that's broken. I use one that ignores insignificant differences involving blank space.

Comment: I have the same problem. I need to keep trailing blank spaces but I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
set trim off
set trims off
```

Comment: I tried and these settings works on output not on the input files